# Spark - how to get random unique rows

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I need a way to get some x number of random rows from a dataset which are unique. I tried `sample` method of dataset class but it sometimes pick duplicate rows.

Dataset's sample method:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#sample-boolean-double-

Answer (score 2):

Sample Function with withReplacement=>'false' would always pick distinct rows `df1.sample(false, 0.1).show()`

> sample(boolean withReplacement, double fraction)

Consider below example:

where withReplacement => 'true' gave duplicate rows which can be verified by count, but withReplacement => 'false' did not.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = ((1 to 10000).toList).zip(((1 to 10000).map(x=>x*2))).toDF("col1", "col2")
// df1.sample(false, 0.1).show()

println("Sample Count for with Replacement : " +  df1.sample(true, 0.1).count)
println("Sample Count for with Out Replacement : " +  df1.sample(false, 0.1).count)
df1.sample(true, 0.1).groupBy($"col1", $"col2").count().filter($"count">1).show(5)
df1.sample(false, 0.1).groupBy($"col1", $"col2").count().filter($"count">1).show(5)

Sample Count for with Replacement : 978
Sample Count for with Out Replacement : 973
+----+-----+-----+
|col1| col2|count|
+----+-----+-----+
|7464|14928|    2|
|6080|12160|    2|
|6695|13390|    2|
|3393| 6786|    2|
|2137| 4274|    2|
+----+-----+-----+
only showing top 5 rows

+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2|count|
+----+----+-----+
+----+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use **sample** function with withReplacement of false, for example, you can use:

```
val sampledData=df.sample(withReplacement=false,0.5)
```

but this is **NOT** guaranteed to provide exactly the fraction of the total count of your given Dataset.
for doing that, after you get your sampled data by **sample** function, take X entity of sampled data.